# Is there a way to use both relative and absolute year ranges on the jQuery Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

For the [datepicker control](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) in jQuery UI, is there a way to mix absolute ranges with a relative range?

For example, how would you express, I want the year to only go back to 2005, but only show up to the current year?

I've tried mixing the two, using something like '2005:+0', but this results in no years being available in the menu.

### Year Range documentation:

> yearRange
>
> Type:
>       String
>   Default:
>       '-10:+10'
>
> Control the range of years displayed in the year drop-down: either relative to current year (-nn:+nn) or absolute (nnnn:nnnn).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. Just need to use a Date object to get the current year.

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/upipu)**

Code from Demo

```
$(function () 
{
    $('#txtStartDate').datepicker(
    {
        showOn: "both",
        yearRange: "2005:" + new Date().getFullYear(),
        dateFormat: "dd M yy",
        firstDay: 1, 
        changeFirstDay: false,
        changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true

    }); 
});
```